# Uploading SmbFile using Apache Commons HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, jcifs

I have been trying to upload SmbFile using Apache Commons HttpClient, Existing system uses `org.​apache.​commons.​httpclient.​methods.​multipart.FilePart` with native java.io.File, I need to modify it to support smbfile but both FilePart and FilePartSource seems to accept `java.io.File` only. Is there a way i can cast `jcifs.smb.SmbFile` to `java.io.File` or is there any other workaround to achieve this?

**Update:**
I am making this edit to give full picture of my requirement, so that it might be useful for someone trying to answer.

I want to upload a file that resides in shared file server to some HTTP URL. As said earlier, existing system uses Apache Commons HttpClient to achieve this, but unfortunately it requires Native IO file.  I am unable to create Native IO file object, since the file is inside password protected file server. I made a workaround to connect the network drive using NET command in windows there by creating native file object. however this method is not consistent because sometimes i am getting **System error 1312 has occurred. A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.**

If the information provided is not sufficient, please post a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i have found the workaround to make things work, i am sharing this for someone coming here looking for the answer.

As of now, there is no direct method available (correct me if i am wrong). Only way i know to make this work is to create a SmbFile using.

```
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(filePath, ntlmAuth);
```

then, create inputstream out of smbFile by using,

```
InputStream is = new SmbFileInputStream(smbFile);
```

Convert inputstream to byte array using Apache Commons IOUtils (other methods can also be used, my choice was Apache).

```
byte[] fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Create ByteArrayPartSource object,

```
PartSource ps = new ByteArrayPartSource(fileName, fileBytes);
```

Then FilePart can be created using the partsource object.

```
new FilePart("uploadedFile", ps);
```

Voila, now you can upload your file using Apache Commons HttpClient.

Anyone having better approach than this, please feel free to post.